# How to get categories product in archive.php in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, archive, categories, taxonomy-terms, custom-field-type

I would like to display categories (from taxonomy-product_category) in archive-product.php.

Get categories:

- Fruit
- Herbs
- Salad
- Vegetables

See screenshot what I mean:

[image]

When I added coding in archive-product.php:

```
<?php
$args = array(
'post_type'              => 'product',
'taxonomy'               => 'product_category',
'hierarchical'           => 1,
'nopaging'               => false,
'posts_per_page'         => '2',
'posts_per_archive_page' => '10',
'ignore_sticky_posts'    => true,
'order'                  => 'rand',
);

echo '<div class="container">';
echo '<div class="row">';
// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post();
    echo '<div class="col-lg-4">';
    echo '<a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">';
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
        the_post_thumbnail(array(486,226));
    }
    the_title();
    the_content();
    echo '</a>';
    echo '</div>';
}
} else {
// no posts found
echo wpautop( 'Sorry, no posts were found' );
}
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
// Previous/next post navigation.
            previous_post_link( '%link', 'Prev post in category', true 
);
            next_post_link( '%link', 'Next post in category', true );
// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

But not display categories (Fruit, Herbs, Salad, Vegetables)

Would anyone know about this?

Thanks,

Shaun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the list of all product categories using Below code

```
    $orderby = 'name';
$order = 'asc';
$hide_empty = false ;
$cat_args = array(
    'orderby'    => $orderby,
    'order'      => $order,
    'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
);

$product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $cat_args );

if( !empty($product_categories) ){
    echo '

<ul>';
    foreach ($product_categories as $key => $category) {
        echo '

<li>';
        echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($category).'" >';
        echo $category->name;
        echo '</a>';
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>


';
}
```

Comment: thanks, it works. How can I add img src="" if there is no image upload will be placeholder automatically? 

Thanks, Shaun.

Comment: I use a ACF PRO for image in taxonomy category how to add image `<img class="img-fluid" src="get_field('product_cat_image')"` in echo'';

Thanks

Shaun.

Comment: I try add this but not display product image via ACF PRO `$product_categories = get_field('product_category' );
if( !empty($product_categories) ){
    echo '<div class="container">';
    echo '<div class="row">';
    foreach ($product_categories as $key => $category) {
        echo '<div class="col-lg-4">';
        echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($category).'" >';
        echo $category->name;
        echo '<img src="' . $category['url'] . '" alt="' . $category['alt'] .'">';
        echo '</a>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}`

Comment: Do you mean you need to display a dummy placeholder image if the product category image is not present?

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code:

```
$args = array(
        'taxonomy'=> 'product_category',
        'order'    => 'DESC',
        );
$categories = get_categories($args);
print_r($categories);
```

Comment: @Makadia I added code above but some message on screen it say NULL, hello world post see screenshot: http://bubblei.co.uk/hDi01b.png